# Django Error - ImportError: cannot import name 'first_app' from 'first_project'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

I am new to Django and was starting with the new Project.

I faced this issue while I was trying to pass in application URLs.

**ImportError: cannot import name 'first_app' from 'first_project'
(E:\Project\DjangoProject\first_project\first_project_*init*_.py)**

[view.py inside the first_app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgGmd.png)

[urls.py inside the first_app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWOTv.png)

[urls.py inside the first_project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jbvhf.png)

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: remove the first line, you don't import apps from the project

Comment: Yes sure Willem, I will make a note to include code, this time I just included the screenshots just to show the directories.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the:

```
from first_project import first_app
```

in your `first_app/urls.py`. Normally the Python *root* path is located at the directory that contains the `manage.py` file, so there is no module named `first_project`.

Comment: Thanks , actually I only removed it from first_app/urls.py
Now I removed from the first_project/urls.py as well , and it works.


Thanks , was really helpful !

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the path in `settings.py` like the following:

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
sys.path.insert(0, BASE_DIR)
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'backend/apps'))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'backend/extra_apps'))
```

Comment: actually the **from first_project import first_app** was causing an error.